# FFMPEG saving frame from video works in localhost but not working in live server

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to take a frame from a video. My code is working all fine in localhost but, fails to execute in server.

Code I'm executing:

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

$video = $ffmpeg->open($File_temp_name);

$video
     ->frame(\FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(1))
     ->save($saveLocation);
```

This code is executing fine in localhost but, when I execute the same in server it is showing an error

```
Exception 'FFMpeg\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to save framesexception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException' with message 'ffmpeg failed to execute command'
```

Command Getting executed is:

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-ss' '00:00:01.00' '-i' '/tmp/php02MmoD' '-vframes' '1' '-f' 'image2' '/home/project/public_html/dev/frontend/web/uploads/temp-video-frames/1499319488-act-thumbnail.jpg'
```

I've tried to execute the command in terminal and found it executing without any error and save frame in desired location. But, when I run it through my code it is throwing above error